# UITableview Cell height is changing on scrolling tableview in iOS 14.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, ios14

UITableview Cell Height is changing on scrolling table view, I am using dynamic height for table view cell.

Basically I'm working on a chat screen and using two custom classes for incoming and out-going message and everything is handled dynamically.

it was working till iOS 13 and getting issue on ios 14

using in viewDidLoad

```
 self.chatTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 172
    self.chatTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

and using

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}
```

for dynamic height handling

rest I have also tried the hugging property on label

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  self.layoutIfNeeded()
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    super.didMoveToSuperview()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

in tableview cell, but didn't see any difference

Answer (score 0):

It must be because of the data in the cells.Try removing the below line and give a static height if you want so then the height will be same throughout.
self.chatTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

Comment: I tried removing this line but getting same result, the cells are of dynamic size according to the content, smaller cells take size of bigger cells and bigger one take size of smaller one